# Predicatebuilder with datetime string comparisson

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linqkit

i just start using linq kit and i think it's awesome but i have a 2 problems

i have this collection of items that can be filtered by several conditions
a,b,c,d,e(non important) and  someDate (datetime)

so i have a predicate like this

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Item>();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
        {
            predicate = predicate.And(p => p.a.Contains(filter));
            predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.b.Value.Contains(filter));
            predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.c.Value.Contains(filter));
            predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.d.Name.Contains(filter));
            predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.e.Contains(filter));
        }
// Get items depending on previous predicate
        var items= (from item in _context.Items.AsExpandable()
                           select item).Where(predicate).Where(m => m.Active).ToList();
```

but when i try to use

```
predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.someDate.ToShortDateString().Contains(filter));
```

because im not using a specific date to compare but a incomplete string 
such as 8/1 or 08/01, maybe just 8 or maybe just the year, so i cannot make an operation between dates.

and throws this error.

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToShortDateString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

and i got from this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/730a88e2-392a-4753-8ea6-129f4720c3e4/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-systemstring-toshortdatestring-method-and-this) that its because linq to entities can't parse the date time to string because if the different culture settings.

even if i use ToString("d") i would hate to start to do all this all over again.

so the question is

> Does anybody knows a way to make the predicate builder work with date.tostring().contains() ????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ToShortDateString is a C# construct and the database doesn't understand it. Just compare the dates directly in your predicate builder.

```
//use some kind of operator. I chose ==.
//if you are passing a date as a string, you need to parse that date first, then do the comparison.
DateTime filterDate;
if(DateTime.TryParse(filter, out filterDate))
   predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.someDate == filterDate);
//Why would you do the date conversion to a string and see if that date contains another string?
```

Comment: yes actually that was what i end doing, if its something close to a datetime try parse it and if so then add it to the predicate. thank you.

Comment: if someDate = "2015-01-01 12:30:00" and filterDate is "2015-01-01". This fails as it return empty result. Is there a better way to compare just the Date part?

Comment: @jmogera here you go

 DateTime filterDate;

                if(DateTime.TryParseExact(searchValue,
                       "dd/MM/yyyy",
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                       DateTimeStyles.None,
                       out filterDate))
                {
                    DateTime startOfDate = filterDate.Date;
                    DateTime endOfDate = AbsoluteEnd(filterDate);

                    predicate = predicate.And(s => s.DATE_ADDED.HasValue && (startOfDate <= s.DATE_ADDED.Value && s.DATE_ADDED.Value <= endOfDate));
                }